# Silverlight disappears

Tags: silverlight

We have an `asp:Silverlight` tag on one of our aspx pages and has been working happily for years:

```
<asp:Silverlight ID="Xaml1" runat="server" MinimumVersion="2.0" Source="~/ClientBin/FHH.UploadManager.xap" Width="97%" Height="320" />
```

The user selects multiple files, which are listed in the Silverlight API, then the user left-clicks on a file and selects what *type* of file it is, then the files are uploaded and end up in different folders depending on the *type*.

As an enhancement it is required that we have another *type* and we amended the Silverlight project to include this extra type, creating a new xap file. This worked fine in test but when it was built for the live environment the Silverlight tag disappears from the screen.

I have browsed through various forums, including Stackoverflow and found the suggestion that we should use `<object>`, but when I tried that it gave an error message: ‘Could not download the Silverlight application’.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have resolved this problem, we were trying to point to a web service with the wrong URL, 2 URLs could be used and we were using the wrong one.